# duplicated function fails for ff date vectors

Tags: r, duplicates, ff, ffbase

Hi I am trying to remove duplicates from a ff vector that contains dates using the duplicated function of the ffbase package and the following code:

```
v1 <- c("24-Mar-94", "24-Mar-94", "27-Mar-94", "28-Jun-1986", "29-Jul-1988", "28-Jun-1986", "15-Jan-1999", "13-Jan-1999")
v1.d <- as.Date(v1, format="%d-%b-%y")
v1.ff <- as.ff(v1.d)
v2 <- v1.ff[!duplicated(v1.ff)]
```

However I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("as.hi") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.hi' applied to an object of class "Date"
```

Is there any way around this problem without having to coerce the v2 vector to a ram object first?

Comment: I suppose you don't want to use `duplicated` before converting to ff?

Comment: exactly. This is a "truncated" example. I already have the ff vector in memory through an ffload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ff)
v1 <- c("24-Mar-94", "24-Mar-94", "27-Mar-94", "28-Jun-1986", "29-Jul-1988", "28-Jun-1986", "15-Jan-1999", "13-Jan-1999")
v1.d <- as.Date(v1, format="%d-%b-%y")
v1.ff <- as.ff(v1.d)
v2 <- v1.ff[ !duplicated(v1.ff[,])  ]
```

Output:

```
> v1.d
[1] "1994-03-24" "1994-03-24" "1994-03-27" "2019-06-28" "2019-07-29" "2019-06-28" "2019-01-15" "2019-01-13"
> v2
[1] "1994-03-24" "1994-03-27" "2019-06-28" "2019-07-29" "2019-01-15" "2019-01-13"
```

And it's deduped.

`ff` objects need to be particularly sliced/subset in order to appropriately use functions on them. One of the ways is the above using `[,]` or `[]` (for this one since it's a vector) in order to create a vector with all of the elements and then use `duplicated` on it.

Comment: Also, I find [this](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/ff.pdf) very helpful to find out a few details about ff if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use sapply to only get the unique dates first then cast to the ffbase object

```
library(ffbase)
v1 <- c("24-Mar-94", "24-Mar-94", "27-Mar-94", "28-Jun-1986", "29-Jul-1988", "28-Jun-1986", "15-Jan-1999", "13-Jan-1999")
v1<-sapply(v1,unique)
v1.d <- as.Date(v1, format="%d-%b-%y")
v1.ff <- as.ff(v1.d)
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your response but sorry for not being entirely clear: this code is a "concise example" of what I am trying to do, and the first two lines are just serving for this purpose. So assume that v1.ff is a very large vector, created by ffload. So I would like to work just with the ff vector, and not with ram copies of it if possible.